# Is there a good way to upload a full size image and then display smaller versions on the fly?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, image-scaling

I'm trying to find a good way to distribute image on my webapp.
The ideal would be that the user upload a "big" full size of an image on S3, and when displayed on the website in different context, smaller versions of this images are displayed.
Of course they need to be cached/stored somewhere otherwise the server would quickly be exhausted...

Is there a good strategy to implement this in Node/Express ?

Thanks for your input !

Comment: An alternative option: Take a look at http://cloudinary.com/ and https://www.imgix.com/ -- They will convert to thumbnails on-the-fly!

Comment: Have you considered using AWS Lambda? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser.html

Comment: Yeah I checked the saas solutions but they can get expensive =/

Comment: I'm gonna check AWS lambda, looks really interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically resize a picture when it is uploaded to Amazon S3, consider using **AWS Lambda**.

A Lambda function can be associated with an S3 bucket. When an object is uploaded/updated/deleted, the Lambda function can be triggered. The function can then do pretty-much anything, such as resizing a picture.

In fact, there's an example that does that in the documentation: [AWS Lambda Walkthrough 2: Handling Amazon S3 Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser.html)

AWS Lambda already has ImageMagick installed, which can make the resizing very simple. Lambda can be coded in Node and Java, with other languages to be released.